# are isometries on euclidean plane translations

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetry

Let $m$ be an isometry in euclidean plane that changes orientation. Prove that $m \circ m$ is a translation.I do not have an idea how to start the proof of this exercise.

Comment: A good way to start is to find all orientation reversing isometries.

Comment: I'm sorry, what  is $m*2$?

Comment: It is m to power 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The orientation-reversing isometries of the Euclidean plane are the reflections and glide reflections. If you apply a reflection twice, you get back the original shape so the translation is trivial. Now, what happens in the other case?